# Redis Queue is using multithreading or multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, redis

I found that Redis Queue is a good broker to start the a new task for processing. However, I don't know whether Redis Queue is using Multithreading or Multiprocessing in Python?.

The original repo is here:
https://github.com/rq/rq

"RQ (Redis Queue) is a simple Python library for queueing jobs and processing them in the background with workers"

Furthermore, what is the meaning of workers here? Is it processors (CPU cores) in the computer?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Redis Queue* is indeed a **distributed** task queue, which similar to [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html). The task/job is typically distributed across machines (on which deploy worker). It differs from the regular multi-process or thread which using multiprocessing standard library.

The [`worker`](https://python-rq.org/docs/workers/) is a process which consume the task/job from [Redis](https://redis.io/) (which acting as a message queue here, like RabbitMQ, Kafka), and then process the task, and send back the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. I can fully understand what you say.